Displaying Image Name on Each Desktop/Space Under macOS Sonoma
After updating my M1 MacBook Pro to Sonoma (macOS 14.6) the process I built to display the image name on each space under Ventura broke.  (I detailed this process here).
It seems Apple changes the method used for finding and displaying images with every OS update.  Under Sonoma, it would appear the sqlite3 database at ~/Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db is no longer valid.  Testing this, I moved the file out of that folder and restarted.  The .db file was created but is zero-byte.  And does not get updated when the image changes.
So, where does Sonoma store the image path and information?  I have five desktops/spaces, each with its own image source and change rate, and they work as expected, but I can't find out where the Mac is keeping that information.  I tried querying ChatGPT, but none of its answers gave me any help.  How about a human???
